# Can you skip the next iteration of a for loop in python?

Tags: python

For this code:

```
for i, num in enumerate(range(20)):
    if num > 10:
        i += 1
    print(num)
```

The idea is to get it to skip every other iteration after num > 10, however it just prints all the items in the range.

Is there a way to skip the next/several iteration(s) of a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

> skip every other iteration after num > 10

Generate a range that fulfils that without needing anything special within the loop itself:

```
from itertools import chain

for i, num in enumerate(chain(range(10), range(10, 20, 2))):
    print(i, num)
```